# Fragment Backport requires seperate class for the backport and for the honeycomb?

Tags: android, backport

Am I missing something important in this, or do you have to maintain a seperate version of all your fragments for the backported classes, and for the native honeycomb fragments?

-- Attempting to use the backported fragments on honeycomb was expected to do a fall-through and use the native, not crash because of a ClassCastException

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my, well don't I feel silly.

Found the problem -- I was running a preview version of the emulator, I never remembered to delete it and replace it with a level 11 instance -- works fine in the final Honeycomb emulator.

Answer (score 2):

You should only need to extend the Fragment classes provided for you in the JAR file that comes with the Compatibility plug-in. No need to maintain two classes for both platforms.

Take a look at the API Demos example that comes with the compatibility download, specifically the FragmentLayoutSupport demo.

Incidentally, what is the ClassCastException you are seeing?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.darkdna.slmap_fragmented.MapFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment` -- I can provide the full stack trace if you need it -- MapFragment is a subclass of `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Answer (score 1):

for me in this situation helped a simply replacing rows:

```
setContentView(R.layout.buttons_fragments);
super.onCreate(bundle);
```

on

```
super.onCreate(bundle);
setContentView(R.layout.buttons_fragments);
```